# How to compare two datasets to check for missing rows which don't exist in the other dataset?

Tags: java

I have built a method which takes two datasets: **dataset1** and **retirementSimpleData**.
It matches the two datasets based on a primary key/number, defined as **cnum**, in the code below.
I wanted to return the value of the difference between the **getAssets** value and the **getSums** value, and this is working, except for one little problem.

Some of the cnums that exist in **dataset1** don't exist in **retirementSimpleData**. Similarly, some **cnums** which may exist in **retirementSimpleData** may not exist in
**dataset1**. This is resulting in no data being returned for that **cnum**.

I would like to implement two passes at the end which check in one direction to see if I missed anything. The second pass would check in the opposite direction.
However, not sure how I would go about implementing this.

```
 public void getReportData(int index) {

        String date1 = Util.dateTimeToShortString(reportDate);
        String date2 = reportDao.getPreviousRetirementDate(date1);

        List<SurveyCompareAssetsCheckData> dataset1 = reportDao.getSurveyCheckCompareAssetsData(date1);

        List<RetSurveyAssets> retirementSimpleData = reportDao.findRetSurveyByDate(date1);

        for (SurveyCompareAssetsCheckData surveyCompareAssetsCheckData : dataset1) {
            for (RetSurveyAssets surveyCompareAssetsCheckData2 : retirementSimpleData) {
                if (surveyCompareAssetsCheckData.getCnum() == surveyCompareAssetsCheckData2.getCnum()) {
                    surveyCompareAssetsCheckData.setRetirementsimple(surveyCompareAssetsCheckData2.getSums());
                    surveyCompareAssetsCheckData.setDifference(surveyCompareAssetsCheckData.getAssets() - surveyCompareAssetsCheckData2.getSums());
```

Caveat: **dataset1** and **retirementSimpledata** both use existing SQL pulls which I am not allowed to touch, otherwise I would have simply defined new SQL for these methods in my "DAOImpl." Therefore, I have to work with the data I am getting, and programmatically check for this.

Below, is the report which is being generated with my code. As you can see, I am ending up with zeros, which is showing the difference (incorrectly) as zeros, because Cnum #45, in this example simply doesn't exist in the second dataset (**retirementSimpleData**)
[image]

Comment: Note that "Assets" minus "Retirement SIMPLE" should give us a difference between the two. For example Cnum #45, which has Assets as 64,583,151 minus 0 gives us 0. This is false. It should have given us 64,583,151, as nothing gets subtracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the datatype of  Cnum, if it is `int` then default value is Zero.

You have to add else-if condition to check for example:

```
else if (surveyCompareAssetsCheckData2.getCnum()== 0){

-------- logic here --------------------

}
else if (surveyCompareAssetsCheckData.getCnum() ==0){

----------logic here -----------

}
```

Comment: Everything, except Name is a double.

Comment: I was trying the else if approach before, but I wasn't sure how to implement it into my existing code, which kept breaking when I tried... :(

Comment: Can you post the code for else if condition... what's the data type of cSum...if string check for empty or null if int check for zero...

Comment: Also, per your comment,---"Assets" minus "Retirement SIMPLE" should give us a difference between the two. For example Cnum #45, which has Assets as 64,583,151 minus 0 gives us 0. This is false. It should have given us 64,583,151, as nothing gets subtracted    --- you are not getting the proper data because the  if condition is false and control is not going inside if statement to execute the computation.